# Software to track application profile

Tags: performance, memory-usage, .profile, tracker, ram-usage

I am developing a software for number theory investigation, and I am suspicious that is leaking memory.

It would be very nice to log the CPU, and RAM usage of this program through some application. Is there any?

Grateful for the attention,

Yuri S VB.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind is what's usually used to look at memory leaks and related problems.